# Editing ListBox with Live/Preview?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am currently customizing a ListBox. With that I mean adding an image-element, second line-element etc. to one listItem.

The itemSource is a List in C#, therefore I have no preview of the items in Expression Blend/VS. And that's the pain.

Because I have always to edit the XAML and then deploy to check. And this goes on and on until the last pixel is correct.

Isn't there a way, of editing a ListBox with custom items (with a dynamic itemSource) live in Blend/VS?

That would really fasten up my developing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how your controls look like in design time, you must use SampleData. There are several ways to do it, it depends on your framework.

Let's say you have a page named MainPage.xaml. If you don't have view model already, create a new one and name it MainViewModel.cs. Define all public properties that will be used for binding.
Once you have your view model, create new file in a folder named SampleData and name it MainViewModelSampleData.xaml.

Now, in the MainPage.xaml add the following attribute to the page element:

```
d:DataContext={d:DesignData Source=SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}
```

Also set Build Action for MainViewModelSampleData.xaml to DesignData.

Now, if you want to display data in your MainPage, you need to define all properties in the sample data file. For example:

```
// view model contains public properties Title of type string and Children of type
// PersonViewModel which contains properties Name and Age (string and int respectively)
<local:MainViewModel xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myapp"
                     Title="Title">
    <local:MainViewModel.Children>
        <local:ChildViewModel Name="John" Age="31" />
    </local:MainViewModel.Children>
</local:MainViewModel>
```

You should now see your page filled with data in your design view. This way by using MVVM you can create mock data quickly. That will ensure that you can design your view around existing data without running the application.

Read more on the following links:

- [31 Days of Mango | Day #18: Using Sample Data](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/18/31-days-of-mango-day-18-using-sample-data/)
- [Modify sample data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341407%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)
- [Generate sample data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341450%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)
- [Using Blend Sample data at Design time and real data at Runtime](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/02/02/using-blend-sample-data-at-design-time-and-real-data-at-runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

I now know how to do that.
If anyone if you guys ever stumble upon this problem, do this:

Copy all the XAML you wrote in the stackpanel of your itemtemplate

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
             //...
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And copy it up to `<ListBox> //Here </ListBox>`
There you can edit it in the designer.

And when you're done, just copy the code back to the StackPanel.